# jQuery AddClass matching class and value

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have the following:

```
<span class="dateStart" val="0">2016-09-16</span> | 
<span class="dateStart" val="1">2016-09-15</span> |
```

Using jQuery how can I add a class of `selected` to the `<span>` that has `class=dataStart` **AND** `val=1`.

I tried:

```
$('.dateStart[value="0"]').addClass('selected');
$('.dateStart[val="0"]').addClass('selected');
$('.dateStart[attr-val="0"]').addClass('selected');
```

But none of them work. Am I even close?

Comment: The second line of the example should work. The only reason it doesn't is because you're looking for a value of `L` instead of `1`. Also note that `val` is not a valid attribute of a `span` so your HTML will be invalid.

Comment: Is your font confusing you between `1` and `l`? ;)

Comment: Second line will work if you change `L` to `1`.

Comment: sorry - my bad, the actual script has a mixture of letters and numbers for the `val`, and I copied the wrong one. I will adjust the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add class "selected" in a span having class "dateStart" and attribute "val" having "1" so selector should be `$('.dateStart[val="1"]').addClass('selected');`

```js
function getSelected(){
  $('.dateStart[val="1"]').addClass('selected');
}
```

```css
.selected{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="dateStart" val="0">2016-09-16</span> | 
<span class="dateStart" val="1">2016-09-15</span> |
<br/><br/>
<button onclick="getSelected()">Click Here</button>
```